# How to serialize task executions with TypeScript when using fp-ts?

Tags: typescript, parallel-processing, fp-ts

I have some code that turns values in an array into asynchronous calls:

```
const createDiscordChannels = flow(
    A.map((channel: CreateChannelDto) => ({
        ...channel,
        provider,
        externalServerId: providerId,
    })),
    //*  We need to check all the channels before we do anything
    //* because otherwise we can end up in an inconsistent state
    A.map(agentDispatcher.isChannelValid), //  returns TaskEither
    A.map(TE.flatMap(agentDispatcher.ensureChannelExists)), //  creates race condition
    A.map(RTE.fromTaskEither),
    RTE.sequenceArray
);
```

My problem is that `A.map(TE.flatMap(agentDispatcher.ensureChannelExists))` will create a bunch of `TaskEither`s that are executing in parallel creating a race condition.

Is there a way to create and immediately **await** a `TaskEither` to execute them in a sequence instead of in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to use [`sequenceSeqArray`](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/ReaderTaskEither.ts.html#sequenceseqarray) which will run each of the tasks sequentially and collect up the results into a single `ReaderTaskEither`. You're currently using `RTE.sequenceArray` which is similar, but has the behavior you're describing where each of the promises is started in parallel.